# Override table name in Vendor Model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, vendor

I'm working on a Laravel 8 project and included a package with models and migrations. One of the package models has the same name as an already existing model.

I have added a prefix to the migrations, and now need to add the table name to the vendor models. I have seen some post about this but I can't get this fixed.

I have created a new class which extends the vendor model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Vendor\Package;

class PreModel extends Laravel\Package\Model 
{
    protected $table = 'pre_model';
}
```

At this point I'm lost. The post I have read say that I need to make a alias right now, but will this also override my existing model?

What is the right way to override the table name of a vendor model?

Answer (score 0):

If your existing model table  not have foreign keys, indexes and unique-s, then  will be easier to rename it in new migration

> Schema::rename($from, $to);